# Playing mp4 video with Phonegap on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, video, cordova, mp4

I have a phonegap application targeting iPad that needs to embed a video on one of its pages. I've found forum posts and other help claiming this is possible using the video tag from HTML5.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
<video id="video01" width="770" height="433" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="splash.png">
<source src="movies/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

This code snippet works great in Safari, but when loaded via Phonegap onto the iPad shows the splash image with a crossed-over play button (like the video didn't load right).

Perhaps is there a nuance with playing video on iOS I'm not aware of? Or is there a small formatting issue for the video itself.  The video was formatted as h264 wrapped in a mp4 container.

Comment: Are you using jQuery with phonegap?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the current version (1.7.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the issue is in your video codec.  Try setting your h.264 Level to 3.1 or lower.

I ran into a similar issue recently.  My problem was in my video codec, I was rendering video in Adobe After Effects (CS5.5) and when exporting H.264 my settings were on Level: 5.1.  I came across this post on [video bitrates on ipad](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2505627?start=0&tstart=0) and saw that the highest setting might be 3.1.  I figured "why not" and gave it a try.  It worked.